# Magento 2 - Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'InvalidArgumentException'

Tags: php, magento, magento2

I am deploying magento2 project into my localhost.

After downloading all the files and db, I am getting this error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'InvalidArgumentException' with message 'Constant name is expected.' in D:\wamp64\www\zerofriction\vendor\magento\framework\Data\Argument\Interpreter\Constant.php on line 23
>       InvalidArgumentException: Constant name is expected. in D:\wamp64\www\zerofriction\vendor\magento\framework\Data\Argument\Interpreter\Constant.php on line 23

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I got the same fatal error when I was trying to disable the caches, because I have been developing a module, then I disabled my module and the issue was resolved.

Please check below link,
https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/124464/55865